# How do I search for a substring in a JSON field in MySQL (Knex/Bookshelf)?

Tags: mysql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm using Bookshelf/Knex for an ORM. I've got a MySQL database, with a table which has a JSON field called "data." Inside that field, there is a key "title" and a key "message." I want to return all rows which have substring "searchString" in either data.title or data.message. How can I do this?

Would this work?

```
qb.raw(`data->'title' LIKE ${searchString} OR data->'message LIKE ${searchString}`)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this within your actual SQL query?

Comment: If I have to drop down into knex.raw, yes.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to do it without SQL injection hole:

```
const results = await new Modelname()
                .query((qb) => {
                        qb.whereRaw(
                           `JSONColumnName->
                               '$.JSONFieldName' LIKE ?`, [`%${searchString}%`])
                })
                .fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
const results = await new Modelname()
                .query((qb) => {
                        qb.whereRaw(
                           `JSONColumnName->
                               '$.JSONFieldName' LIKE "%${searchString}%"`)
                })
                .fetch();
```

"JSONColumnName" is the name of the JSON column, "JSONFieldName" is the name of some JSON field inside that column.

Comment: This solution has SQL injection vulnerability. You should never interpolate searchString directly to the SQL string.